# Printing file to my program in python not working

Tags: python-3.x

Edit: Apologies for my first post, wasn't aware of the poor etiquette!

So I am trying to display an imported file to my program in Python. I have been using PyCharm and can't get this file (or any file, .txt to be precise) to open anywhere... I have tried multiple solutions and methods on the internet and none of them work, so the only thing I can think of is it being my code...

Here I defined the section which allows users to open a file and then the label changes to the directory path:

```
def openfile():
    filename = askopenfilename()
    wordlist_label = Label( root , text = "" )
    wordlist_label.pack()
    wordlist_label.config( text = "File Path: " + filename )
```

So with this I have the variable "filename". I want to print the contents of this file. I have tried this method and many others, but see nothing in my program:

```
f = open( filename ,'r' )
for line in f:
    print ( line )
f.close()
```

I would appreciate any help I could get, thank you!

Comment: "it doesn't work" --> [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: please check you question again by @TessellatingHeckler it will be useful to raise your content quality up

Comment: No worries, apologies

Comment: I've edited it, hope that is better

Comment: It sounds like it's probably not opening the file correctly.  Can you enclose the opening function in a try: block, and print the output of any caught exception?

Comment: Also, can you publish the source for askopenfilename() ?

Comment: askopenfilename() is imported with tkinter, I tried the try function and nothing happened

Comment: Can you do a `repr` on `f` after the open call, and post the results?

Comment: I wasn't commenting about etiquette, I was commenting about the impossibility of troubleshooting a problem when someone won't tell you what the problem is. Your code, for example, runs and prints file contents to the command line. You say you see "nothing" in your program -> a) the wordlist_label doesn't update? b) does PyCharm have a console, and did you look there, and do you count that as part of your program? c) What do you expect to see - you have no code which puts anything from the file in your program? After `print(line)` add `listbox1.insert(END, line)` and that will show file content

Answer (score 0):

A starting point would be to enclose the call to `open` in a `try` block, and print any error messages.  This will likely point you in the right direction.

```
try:
    f = open( filename ,'r' )
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception error: " + e.message)
    raise e
else:
    for line in f:
        print ( line )
    f.close()
```